# Component Dashboard - config not showing

Tags: joomla-4.x, cpanel, dashboard

I have a dashboard setup for my component which works fine but I wanted to allow a user in the administrator usergroup to have access to the components parameters.  So set the permissions in the component to allow this.  When viewing the list of main items in the admin side, the "Options" button appears as I would expect, however, on the dashboard the "Configuration" option doesn't appear as it does for the Super User's.
Any suggestions where to look to see why this is missing greatly appreciated.
In "mycomponent.xml" preset file I have the usual config menuitem setting:

```
    <menuitem
        title="COM_MYCOMPONENT_CONFIGURATION"
        type="component"
        element="com_config"
        link="index.php?option=com_config&amp;view=component&amp;component=com_mycomponent&amp;path=&amp;return=&amp;dashboard=mycomponent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlView of your component in the administrator should have something like the follow in the function adToolbar()

```
if ($user->authorise('core.admin', 'com_yourcomponent') || $user->authorise('core.options', 'com_yourcomponent')) {
            $toolbar->preferences('com_yourcomponent');
}
```

Then in your access.xml in your component need have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access component="com_yourcomponent">
    <section name="component">
            <action name="core.options" title="JACTION_OPTIONS" />
    </section>
</access>
```

This should be enough for get working this in your component toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for your input Carlitorweb however, I do have this in place already which is why (as stated above) the user sees the Options button within the multi list view, but the config link doesn't show up on the Dashboard.  I'm obviously missing something else.